# App works on iPhone but it doesn't work on iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, ios, build, crash, ipod

I have an app that i can deploy on iPhone 3GS or 4 and it work with no problem. But when i try to deploy it on iPod Touch 3rd and 4th gen it builds with no errors but nothing appears except a black screen.
Here is the log that i get from the device when i try to instal the app.

```
Aug 31 10:46:33 unknown misagent[1741] <Error>: libMobileGestalt loadBasebandMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45
Aug 31 10:46:33 unknown misagent[1741] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Aug 31 10:46:33 unknown misagent[1741] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Aug 31 10:46:35 unknown installd[1744] <Error>: libMobileGestalt loadBasebandMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45
Aug 31 10:46:35 unknown installd[1744] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Aug 31 10:46:35 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Killing <SBApplication: 0x1dac2200> 'myApp'  activate:  deactivate:  for app installation
Aug 31 10:46:36 unknown installd[1744] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Aug 31 10:46:36 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Reloading application state for 'myApp' as its modification date has changed
Aug 31 10:46:36 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1748] <Warning>: debugserver-50 for armv6 Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Apple, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1748] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[1740] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1cd13310) uilock state: 1 -> 0
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) platform_supports_camera_import: Platform is configured for camera import
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) media_attach_callback: Inspecting the attached media
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) handle_attached_media: The attached media object is a disk image. Dropping like it's hot.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) media_attach_callback: Inspecting the attached media
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) handle_attached_media: The attached media disk0s2s1 is not removable. Ignoring.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) media_attach_callback: Inspecting the attached media
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) handle_attached_media: The attached media disk0s2 is not removable. Ignoring.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) media_attach_callback: Inspecting the attached media
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) handle_attached_media: The attached media disk0s1 is not removable. Ignoring.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) media_attach_callback: Inspecting the attached media
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) handle_attached_media: The attached media disk0 is not removable. Ignoring.
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:myApp[0x1ab2]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
Aug 31 10:46:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1748] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions for task "(null)".
Aug 31 10:46:39 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Aug 31 10:46:39 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1750] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Aug 31 10:46:39 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1750] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/8ASD873E87-A23C-4234-8848-234KJAS23 [69] (sandbox)
Aug 31 10:46:48 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1749] <Notice>: (0x3ec9048c) idle_timer_callback: Exiting after idle timeout
```

Comment: Any update on this? I am currently stacked with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have resolved this very easily. Even I have stated my nib files in pList, somehow only iPad nib file was displayed as Main Interface when I look at the project target summary. So I put there the one that should be there and now it is working on IPod as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get mobile type info (IMEI etc presumably), and there won't be any on an iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look for 2 posible causes: iOS versions, phone specific code.

For the first option, I'd try to use the iphone simulator on different versions (you can change that on the simulator itself). If that doesn't look like the problem, then try to search for a place in your code where you might use phone specific things, like trying to get the IMEI.

Comment: i haven't found any line of code that indicates that. My app is for iPhone and ipad. Ho you have any idea where should i search for that line of code?      i suppose that i should be in AppDelegate or on rootViewController because those are the classes that load first.